Power BI - Top N not showing the highest value
Im doing a football stat dashboard displaying the current stats of the premier league season, i want to show the highest scorer this season (Haaland) who on my table has 10 goals. However when i do the top N function, im getting the second highest which is Diaz. This should be Haaland. Here are some of the screenshots i have obtained, anyone know why its not showing Haaland:



Use the Top Team Scorer.2 instead of Top Team Scorer.1 in the By Value area of the Top N filter.
You are currently looking at the first Top Team Scorer.1 and not the points of the scorer.
